# Asp.net core 2.0 Error -13 EACCES permission denied

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, visual-studio-mac

I have asp.net core 2.0 application run it under vs for mac,
when i run it from CLI its work without any problem,
but when I run it from VS I receive this error:

> "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Libuv.Internal.Networking.UvException Error -13 EACCES permission denied

but after run this command in CLI

> dotnet add package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel
>
> the Error became  System.Net.Sockets.SocketException "Permission denied"

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BuildWebHost(args).Run();//Error occur here
    }

    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .UseKestrel()
    .UseIISIntegration()
    .UseStartup<Startup>()
    .Build();
}
```

How i can solve this issue?

Comment: Show the rest of the message

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We'll need more information to properly help you: what does your code looks like, what specifically is going wrong, and do you have a minimal working example of the issue? See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), the [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) and [Creating a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: thank you,I added the code which throw the Ex

Comment: this is the complete msg "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Libuv.Internal.Networking.UvException Error -13 EACCES permission denied

Comment: @YamanMelhem Don't post additional information as a comment, edit it into the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> thank you
>
> the problem solved
>
> the problem was I should run VS for mac as admin by this command on
>   terminal
>
> sudo /Applications/Visual\ Studio.app